# Getting peak hourly KW for each month and showing the year, month, day, and hour it occurred for past 10 years?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, max

I have electric meter usage data for 22,000 meters that goes back 10 years (2012 to present) and it's stored as hour intervals. So, each individual meter will have (10 years * 365 days * 24 hours) 87,600 records - one for each hour going back 10 years and the KW (usage) for that hour is recorded.

And for each month going back 10 years, I need to show the monthly KW peak and the Year, Month, Day and Hour it occurred grouped by the Substation, Feeder, and Rate. I don't want to show any of the other hours, only the hour the summed KW peaked at for the month.

The table has around 2 billion records, and the raw records look like (I'm skipping hours, but each meter will have 24 records per day, hour 1 to 24, and the KW that was used for that hour):

| Meter | Substation | Feeder | Rate | IntervalDate | IntervalHour | KW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 1 | W1 | Residential | 2022-06-12 | 1 | 2.7 |
| 11111 | 1 | W1 | Residential | 2022-06-12 | 2 | 5.9 |
| 11111 | 1 | W1 | Residential | 2022-06-12 | 24 | 8.3 |
| 22222 | 1 | W1 | Residential | 2022-06-13 | 1 | 4.8 |
| 22222 | 1 | W1 | Residential | 2022-06-13 | 2 | 2.0 |
| 22222 | 1 | W1 | Residential | 2022-06-13 | 24 | 3.7 |
| 11111 | 1 | W1 | Residential | 2022-07-25 | 1 | 10.5 |
| 11111 | 1 | W1 | Residential | 2022-07-25 | 2 | 4.5 |
| 11111 | 1 | W1 | Residential | 2022-07-25 | 24 | 4.5 |
| 22222 | 1 | W1 | Residential | 2022-07-25 | 1 | 15.5 |
| 22222 | 1 | W1 | Residential | 2022-07-25 | 2 | 7.5 |
| 22222 | 1 | W1 | Residential | 2022-07-25 | 24 | 5.5 |
| 33333 | 2 | G1 | Commercial | 2022-07-25 | 1 | 20.4 |
| 44444 | 3 | Z5 | Industrial | 2022-07-25 | 4 | 100.4 |
| 55555 | 5 | J5 | Commercial | 2022-07-25 | 24 | 5.7 |

The Meter can be ignored because it's being grouped down to the Substation, Feeder, Rate, IntervalDate, IntervalHour level. There are 3 different rates, Residential, Commercial, and Industrial.

So, for every month for the past 10 years, I need to show the peak KW grouping by Substation, Feeder, and Rate and which Year, Day, and Hour the KW peak occurred.

@Greg_Pavlik below gets the summed totals using his first query:

```
WITH HOURLY_SUMS AS
(
SELECT
    Substation,
    Feeder,
    Rate,
    IntervalDate,
    IntervalHour,
    SUM(KW) as TotalKW
FROM
    T1
GROUP BY
    Substation, Feeder, Rate, IntervalDate, IntervalHour
)
```

But, the result (not using above data) needs to look like this:

| Year | Month | Day | Hour | Rate | Substation | Feeder | Summed KW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012 | January | 23 | 8 | Residential | 3 | Z5 | 20.5 |
| 2012 | January | 15 | 9 | Commercial | 3 | Z5 | 40.7 |
| 2012 | January | 28 | 7 | Industrial | 3 | Z5 | 100.2 |
| 2012 | February | 23 | 8 | Residential | 3 | Z5 | 20.5 |
| 2012 | February | 15 | 9 | Commercial | 3 | Z5 | 40.7 |
| 2012 | February | 28 | 7 | Industrial | 3 | Z5 | 100.2 |
| .... | ........ | .. | . | .......... | . | .. | ..... |
| 2022 | July | 09 | 6 | Residential | 3 | Z5 | 25.5 |
| 2022 | July | 12 | 5 | Commercial | 3 | Z5 | 48.7 |
| 2022 | July | 02 | 8 | Industrial | 3 | Z5 | 143.2 |

A substation has one or more feeders, which I'm not showing very well with my sample data. But my data has 33 different feeders.

So, the number of result records should be 11,880 (10 years * 12 months * 3 Rates * 33 Feeders).

I appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Have you tried [row_number()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Comment: Yes it is possible with queries, it's just not gonna be fast. Have you considered rolling this stuff up into an Analytics model? Like, do you know why SSAS and PowerBI exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with agg as (
    select Feeder, Substation, Rate, IntervalDate, IntervalHour,
        -- ties within a month are broken by picking the earliest
        row_number() over (
            partition by Feeder, Substation, Rate, eomonth(IntervalDate)
            order by sum(KW) desc, IntervalDate, IntervalHour) as rn,
        sum(KW) as KW
    from T
    group by Feeder, Substation, Rate, IntervalDate, IntervalHour
)
select
    year(IntervalDate) "Year", month(IntervalDate) "Month", day(IntervalDate) "Day",
    IntervalHour as "Hour", Rate, Substation, Feeder, KW as "Summed KW"
from agg where rn = 1;
```

Comment: `eomonth()` is used so that each date within a month gets treated as part of the same partition. All the meters are summed and then the row numbering applies to all the hourly sums within a single month so that you find the one that ranked highest.

Comment: Yes, that's what it's doing with both `IntervalDate` and `IntervalHour` in the `group by`. It's doing the aggregation and the ranking all within that query. Then there's the `row_number()` applies for `order by sum(KW) desc` on the entire month of individual totals.

Comment: Using an aggregate inside an analytic function is a bit of a trick. Grouping and summing is certainly basic SQL. Find the top-N rows in a subset is a very frequent question on here and it's a standard technique these days to use `row_number()`. Tripping over the months and years is a common mistake. No, I wouldn't say it's a highly difficult. If you had this at a job interview this kind of query it might establish that you were fairly competent though.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry, that was just an oversight. You should still be able to confirm the number of rows as you had calculated.

Comment: I've run across some that exist but I couldn't say whether any of them are any good unfortunately.

Comment: `I think this might have the same problem Greg's answer has which is that it's treating all the months as if they are in the same year in the partition... ` Did you see the update? All that needed to change was the window partition to add the year.

Comment: Greg's answer is fundamentally the same. I just observed the minor errors and the back and forth that had not resulting a correct answer. And in case my answer without using `top`, along with the note about ties, was an improvement I went ahead and shared. Reputation points is not a concern.

Answer (score 2):

Updated: Changed the window function to support more than one year.

As indicated in the comments, this is a two-step process. Step one is summing by group. Step two is selecting the rows from Step 1 that are the summed peaks for rate types per month.

The two step process can be a CTE or a subquery. I find the CTE a bit more readable in this case.

```
create table T1(Meter int, Substation int, Feeder varchar(10), Rate varchar(50), IntervalDate date, IntervalHour int, KW float);

insert into T1(Meter, Substation, Feeder, Rate, IntervalDate, IntervalHour, KW) values
( 11111 , 1 , 'W1' , 'Residential' , '2022-07-25', 1, 10.5),
( 22222 , 1 , 'W1' , 'Residential' , '2022-07-25', 1, 4.5),
( 33333 , 2 , 'G1' , 'Commercial' , '2022-07-25',  1, 20.4),
( 44444 , 3 , 'Z5' , 'Industrial' , '2022-07-25',  4, 100.4),
( 55555 , 5 , 'J5' , 'Commercial' , '2022-07-25',  24, 5.7);

with HOURLY_SUMS as
(
select   Substation
        ,Feeder
        ,Rate
        ,year(IntervalDate) Year
        ,month(IntervalDate) Month
        ,IntervalDate
        ,IntervalHour
        ,sum(KW) as TotalKW
from T1
group by Substation, Feeder, Rate, IntervalDate, IntervalHour
)
select   top 1 with ties
         Year
        ,Month 
        ,Substation
        ,Feeder
        ,Rate
        ,IntervalDate PeakIntervalDate
        ,IntervalHour PeakIntervalHour
        ,TotalKW
from HOURLY_SUMS
order by row_number() over
  (partition by Year
               ,Month
               ,Rate
   order by TotalKW desc)
;
```

[(New) SQL Fiddle with sample data.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=26576752732834f547b5f2df768f9dec)

Output:

```
| Substation | Feeder |        Rate | PeakIntervalDate | PeakIntervalHour | TotalKW |
|------------|--------|-------------|------------------|------------------|---------|
|          2 |     G1 |  Commercial |       2022-07-25 |                1 |    20.4 |
|          3 |     Z5 |  Industrial |       2022-07-25 |                4 |   100.4 |
|          1 |     W1 | Residential |       2022-07-25 |                1 |      15 |
```

Comment: Do you want to find the peak row of KW within each partition (Substation, Feeder, Rate, Date, and Hour) and from that calculate the sum for that hour? Or do you want the peak of the sum of all meters within each partition? The sample data does not show meters, so is there enough information in the sample columns to identify a meter? If not, can you add it to the sample?

Comment: Let's see if I have this right. 1) Sum each group based on (Substation, Feeder, Rate, Date, and Hour). 2) From the results in 1, select only the rows with the peak for a whole month from the summed hourly KW for residential, commercial, and industrial. Do I have that right?

Comment: Updated. I think it's got it or should be close enough to tweak to get it.

Comment: The only difference is I can tell between the SQL and your description is the addition of `Feeder` to the window partition. Do you have a larger sample table somewhere?

Comment: It is. I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure just try.

```
SELECT  to_char(to_date(intervaldate,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY') as Year, 
        to_char(to_date(intervaldate,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'Month') as Month,
         to_char(to_date(intervaldate,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'DD') as Day,
         IntervalHour  Hour,
         Rate Substation,
         Substation  Feeder,
         Feeder  Rate,
         KW  Summed KW
FROM     t1;
```